# Settings to change text color in activity textview

Tags: android, settings, preference

[Color Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f47a.jpg)
I'm trying to create a  preference screen in xml folder and the code done in settingsfragment so that user can see TextColor options in settings and click on it to select preferred color using either of these color pickers.
Please help me get how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`TextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary))`;

Answer (score 0):

Get preferred color from user with a spinner. Then use `TextView.setTextColor(int color);` to change it.